# Show all symbolic links in a -> b format for 1 directory and sub directories

Tags: macos, symbolic-link

As title. How can I see a list of symbolic links in the format A -> B starting from a specified directory including all it's sub directories?

This is on a Mac by the way.

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -type l -exec stat -f '%N -> %Y' {} \+
```

%N = name, %Y = target of symbolic link.

Answer (score -1):

Running

```
ls -l `find . -xtype l `
```

while you are in the directory should do the trick. Else, replace `.` with the directory name. Do `man find` to set additional options if you like.

Comment: BSD find doesn't have -xtype, and this doesn't work if the paths have spaces.

Comment: @LauriRanta - sorry, I was away from my Mac and tested this on Linux. Thanks for your more thorough answer!

Comment: so uhh guys, what was the command I was supposed to run to only show the symbolic links on macOSX, would prefer a command that actually works?
@MattDMo